# Show 2^n is O(n!)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, big-o

I am struggling to understand why they are equal. Help would be appreciated.
I have tried saying how *2^n implies doubling n times* but I am not sure how that is similar to a factorial.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133372/show-that-2n-on/133374

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that *2<sup>n</sup>* is *O(n!)*, you need to show that *2<sup>n</sup> ≤ M·n!*, for some constant *M* and all values of *n ≥ C*, where *C* is also some constant.

So let's choose *M = 2* and *C = 1*.

For *n = C*, we see that 2<sup>n</sup> = 2 and *M·n!* = 2, so indeed in that base case the *2<sup>n</sup> ≤ M·n!* is true.

Assuming it holds true for some *n* (≥ C), does it also hold for *n+1*? Yes, because if *2<sup>n</sup> ≤ M·n!* then also *2<sup>n+1</sup> ≤ M·(n+1)!*

The left side gets multiplied with 2, while the right side gets multiplied with *at least* 2.

So this proves by induction that *2<sup>n</sup> ≤ M·n!* for all *n ≥ C*, for the chosen values for *M* and *C*.  By consequence *2<sup>n</sup>* is *O(n!)*.

Comment: A question about the logic of the proof: the truth of the inductive step depends on M=2. How do we know the inductive step still holds when M != 2 (e.g., some fraction like 0.5)?

Comment: M is a constant that you can freely chose, so there is no need to consider a smaller value for M.

Comment: I think I see why the value of M is arbitrary. Letting M=0.5 (or some fractional value), `2^(n+1) ≤ M·(n+1)!` is *at some point true*. Rewriting that statement as `2(2^n) ≤ 0.5(n+1)(n!)`, we see that this is true for `n` such that `2 ≤ 0.5(n+1)` or C≥3.

Comment: Yes there are an infinite number of pairs (M,C) you can choose for proving the point. One is enough as proof.

Answer (score 0):

2^n and n! are not "equal". In formal mathematics, there is an important distinction that is often overlooked when people say "function a is O of b". It just means that asymptotically, b is an upper bound of a. This means that, technically, n is O(n!), 1 is O(n!), etc. These are trivial examples. Likewise, **n! is not O(2^n)**.

> Informally, especially in computer science, the big O notation often
>   can be used somewhat differently to describe an asymptotic tight bound
>   where using big Theta Θ notation might be more factually appropriate
>   in a given context.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Use_in_computer_science)